How to integrate ayden in nxtbn?
I am having trouble integrating the Adyen plugin into my nxtbn Django e-commerce project.
This is how i am trying
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from nxtbn.payment.base import PaymentPlugin, PaymentResponse
from rest_framework import serializers
from nxtbn.settings import get_env_var


class AydenPayloadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    payment_method_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=500, required=True)

class AydenPaymentGateway(PaymentPlugin):
    gateway_name = 'ayden'

